# Adding a graphic to the OpenID login button on ASP.NET MVC Sample

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dotnetopenauth

I'm using the VS 2012 MVC4 (razor) sample (new to pretty much all of this) and I modified the AuthConfig.cs file to allow both OpenID access for Google and Yahoo

```
        OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterGoogleClient();
        OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterYahooClient();
```

Sure enough, those two OpenID options are presented.  I want to modify this so the button shows the appropriate logo.

Does DotNetOpenAuth have a way of returning the image path?  I was thinking if it did, I could modify the ExternalLogin "page".

```
@foreach (AuthenticationClientData p in Model)
{
        <button type="submit" name="provider" value="@p.AuthenticationClient.ProviderName"  title="Log in using your @p.DisplayName account"><img src="" />@p.DisplayName </button>            
}
```

Comment: Why don't you save the logos as local resources in your image folder, name them the same as the DisplayName for each OAuth provider.  Then you could just use <img src="@string.format("{0}.jpg, ", p.DisplayName)"/>

Comment: These buttons themselves are not directly a feature of dotnetopenauth, which is used underneath for the buttons' behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this (sorry it's vb.net code):

In AuthConfig RegisterAuth method create a dictionnary and Add your icon path to the desired image

```
Dim MsExtraData As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
MsExtraData.Add("Icon", VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Images/Microsoft.png"))

' Then pass it as extraData parameter to the register client method
OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterMicrosoftClient(
        clientId:="yourkey",
        clientSecret:="yoursecret",
        displayName:="Microsoft",
        extraData:=MsExtraData)
```

Now go to view _ExternalLoginsListPartial in Views\Account folder
and change button generation code with this :

```
<button type="submit" id="<%: p.DisplayName%>" name="provider" value="<%: p.AuthenticationClient.ProviderName%>" title="Login with <%: p.DisplayName %>"><%: p.DisplayName%>
            <img src="<%: p.ExtraData("Icon")%>" alt="Icon for <%: p.DisplayName%>" />
        </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds good. The Twitter and Facebook signature require an extra field: displayName.

Answer (score -1):

I just used font-awsome to do that task on the _ExternalLoginsListPartials view like so:

```html
        using (Html.BeginForm(Model.Action, "Account", new { ReturnUrl = Model.ReturnUrl }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div id="socialLoginList">
                <p>
                @foreach (AuthenticationDescription p in loginProviders)
                {
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="@p.AuthenticationType" name="provider" value="@p.AuthenticationType" title="Log in using your @p.Caption account"><span class="fa fa-@p.Caption.ToLower()">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>@p.AuthenticationType</button>
                }
                </p>
            </div>
        }
```

That off course provided you are using Font-Awsome but I think it would also work with other glyphicons. Also this is MVC5 and VS2013 but I guess it's still applicable for previous MVC versions since I am using html, css and Razor only.

Hope that helps!